# retrofit2 - правильный запрос к API

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

Хочу достать поля из JSON - ответа посредством API - запроса на получение access-токена Google OAuth.

Загвостка в том, что по той же логике у меня выходит получать данные от своего сервера, а по запросу к серверу Google - нет, хотя в Postman-е всё работает и выдаёт ответ.

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` - ссылка на получение access-токена.

Код на отправку запроса:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("grant_type", getString(R.string.grant_type));
    map.put("id_token", idToken);
    map.put("code", serverAuthCode);
    map.put("client_id", getString(R.string.server_client_id));
    map.put("client_secret", getString(R.string.client_secret));

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    
    ServerConnectionService scs = retrofit.create(ServerConnectionService.class);
    final String[] message = new String[1];
    scs.getGoogleAuthAccessToken(map).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response<ResponseBody>> call, Response<Response<ResponseBody>> response) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.isSuccessful(): " + response.isSuccessful());
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.code: " + response.raw().code());
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.method: " + response.raw().request().method());
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.url: " + response.raw().request().url());

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String ss = response.message();
                    Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.message(): " + ss);
                } else {
                    try {
                        String ss = response.errorBody().string();
                        Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.errorBody(): " + ss);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response<ResponseBody>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onFailure: " + call);
        }
    });
```

Интерфейс для retrofit2:

```
 @retrofit2.http.POST("token")
Call<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> getGoogleAuthAccessToken(@retrofit2.http.QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);
```

В Postman отображается либо при успехе (status 200)

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.GlwJxxxxxxmpYmnq9eZwIUn_QHIBPvBg1B9Jc5ig",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3568,
    "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpT3n6z6tkSYl4EebUkPZrsZOrR3Ip5XkxleT_szruvryX2XD0QKAbMblBHV5No8G59MSj2ol16-kFpMe8sxaFZeL2HQbE4fw0g"
}
```

либо при втором запросе (status 400 Bad request)

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Code was already redeemed."
}
```

Когда пытаюсь дебажить, переменные почему-то пустые:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, я где-то что-то перепутал? Прошу помощи или совета, в каком направлении копать

**Обновлено:**

Добавил строчку в OkHttp для логов запроса:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build();
```

и логи показали :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, сервер правильно отвечает и в логах это видно, но как эти поля достать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте модель на основе json на http://jsonschema2pojo.org

```
public class GoogleAuthModel {

    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    private Integer expiresIn;
    @SerializedName("id_token")
    @Expose
    private String idToken;
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private String error;
    @SerializedName("error_description")
    @Expose
    private String errorDescription;
}
```

интерфейс ретрофита будет выглядеть так

```
POST("token")
Call<GoogleAuthModel> getGoogleAuthAccessToken(@retrofit2.http.QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);
```

и метод колбека будет выглядеть так

```
scs.getGoogleAuthAccessToken(map).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<GoogleAuthModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GoogleAuthModel> call, Response<GoogleAuthModel> response) {
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.isSuccessful(): " + response.isSuccessful());
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.code: " + response.raw().code());
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.method: " + response.raw().request().method());
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.url: " + response.raw().request().url());

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String ss = response.message();
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.message(): " + ss);
                Log.e(TAG_G, "onResponse response.message()response.body().toString(): " + response.body().toString());
                googleAuthModel.setAccessToken(response.body().getAccessToken());
                googleAuthModel.setIdToken(response.body().getIdToken());
                googleAuthModel.setExpiresIn(response.body().getExpiresIn());
                googleAuthModel.setTokenType(response.body().getTokenType());
                googleAuthModel.setError(response.body().getError());
                googleAuthModel.setErrorDescription(response.body().getErrorDescription());

            } else {

                     googleAuthModel.setAccessToken(response.body().getAccessToken());                    googleAuthModel.setIdToken(response.body().getIdToken());
                googleAuthModel.setExpiresIn(response.body().getExpiresIn());
                googleAuthModel.setTokenType(response.body().getTokenType());
                googleAuthModel.setError(response.body().getError());
                googleAuthModel.setErrorDescription(response.body().getErrorDescription());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GoogleAuthModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG_G, "onFailure: ");
        }
    });
```